# Cannot get Trigger Test to work

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I've created a trigger that automatically changes the Lead Status on a Lead record to "Contacted" if a new task is created, but only if the Lead Status had been at the default "New - Not Contacted" before the task creation, otherwise it does not fire. So the trigger works, and now it's time to make some test coverage for it so that I can put it into production, but I can't get the test to run because it doesn't believe that the Lead's status was successfully changed. I read that it may work to try to query the leads that were changed and then using that in the System.assertEquals, but now the test says that there are no rows in the Lead query to test. Here's my trigger:

```
    trigger LeadStatusChange on Task (before insert, before update) {
    String desiredNewLeadStatus = 'Contacted';
    String requiredStatus = 'New – Not Contacted';

    //makes sure that the record being updated is a lead
    List<Id> leadIds=new List<Id>();
    for(Task t:trigger.new){
            if(t.whoId != null && String.valueOf(t.whoId).startsWith('00Q')==TRUE){//check if the task is associated with a lead
                leadIds.add(t.whoId);
            }
    }
    List<Lead> leadsToUpdate=[SELECT Id, Status FROM Lead WHERE Id IN :leadIds AND IsConverted=FALSE];

    //loops through leads and tests if they are 'New - Not Contacted' before changing them to 'Contacted'
    for (Lead l:leadsToUpdate){
        if(l.Status==requiredStatus){
            l.Status=desiredNewLeadStatus;
        }
    }

    try{
        update leadsToUpdate;
    }catch(DMLException e){
        system.debug('Leads were not all properly updated.  Error: '+e);
    }
}
```

And here's my test class:

```
@isTest
private class TestLeadStatusChange{

    //creates new lead with 'New - Not Contacted' Lead Status
    @isTest static void TestLeadWithNewNotContactedLeadStatus(){
        //new lead created with 'New - Not Contacted' lead status
        Lead leadOne = new Lead(Lead_Type__c='Undefined Leads', Region__c='US', Company='Test', LastName='testLastName',
                         Status='New – Not Contacted', Lead_Mode__c='Call',
                         Awareness_Source__c='Advertisement', Rating='Hot', Business_Profile__c='Trader', 
                         Interested_in_Course__c='Lab Class', Area_Suburb__c='testSuburb');
        insert leadOne;

        //performs test
        Test.startTest();
        Task t = new Task(Subject='testSub', ActivityDate=Date.today(), Status='Not Started', Priority='Normal');
        Test.stopTest();

        //Verify that lead status has been updated
        Lead leadTestOne = [select Id, status from Lead where Id = :leadOne.id];
        System.assertEquals(leadOne.status, 'Contacted');

    }

    @isTest static void TestLeadWithUnqualifiedLeadStatus(){

        //new lead created with 'Unqualified' Lead Status
        Lead leadTwo = new Lead(Lead_Type__c='Undefined Leads', Region__c='US', Company='Test', LastName='testLastName',
                         Status='Unqualified', Lead_Mode__c='Call',
                         Awareness_Source__c='Advertisement', Rating='Hot', Business_Profile__c='Trader', 
                         Interested_in_Course__c='Lab Class', Area_Suburb__c='testSuburb');
        insert leadTwo;

        //performs test
        Test.startTest();
        Task t = new Task(Subject='testSub', ActivityDate=Date.today(), Status='Not Started', Priority='Normal');
        Test.stopTest();

        //Verify that lead status has been updated
        Lead leadTestTwo = [select Id, status from Lead where Id = :leadTwo.id];
        System.assertEquals(leadTestTwo.status, 'Unqualified');

    }
}
```

And here's the error message I get in the test failure results on both lines 19 and 39 in the test class:

```
System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
```

And here's line 19 that it's being thrown at:

```
        Lead leadTestOne = [select Id, status from Lead where Id = :leadOne.id];
```

And here's line 39 that it's being thrown at:

```
        Lead leadTestTwo = [select Id, status from Lead where Id = :leadTwo.id];
```

I've tried getting rid of the queries, but the first test still fails because it says that the Lead Status was not successfully changed. Like I said, the trigger works in practice, but not in the test. Any help would be *greatly* appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What line are you getting that error on?

Comment: My fault for not mentioning. I'm getting the error message for both line 19, column 1 and line 39, column 1 on the test class.

Comment: Which lines are those in the snippets above?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'll edit the question to show you.

Comment: In addition to not inserting the Tasks, I don't see where you're specifying a WhoId (= lead.id) for the Tasks. For that reason, your queries won't return results and the assertions will fail.

Comment: All right thanks for the help. I'll give that a shot and see what happens.

Comment: I can't figure out where to specify the WhoId. Is it something I need to change in the test class or the trigger?

Comment: note that you've written the trigger to fail the whole batch if any batch member fails ..this might not be desirable. Applies when inserting a batch of Tasks, say through data loader

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not actually inserting the Tasks. The triggers don't run when they're created in memory, but when they're inserted.

Comment: Thanks I totally forgot about that! I'll pop those in and re-run the test.

Comment: Watch out - crmprogdev is right that the test will still fail without specifying WhoId for your tasks! :)